# Beginner: How to use an array instead of several variables; loops, structs basics

Tags: c, arrays, loops, structure

I am currently trying to make a program to compute grades on a 20 true or false question test for 5 students. 0 is false 1 is true. Basically it is follows:

```
Sample Input:
Enter student name: Nice
Enter their answerkey: 01010101010101010110
Enter student name: Nice1
Enter their answerkey: 01010101010101010110
Enter student name: Nice2
Enter their answerkey: 01010101010101010110
Enter student name: Nice3
Enter their answerkey: 01010101010101010110
Enter student name: Nice4
Enter their answerkey: 01010101010101010110
Enter the Right answerkey: 01010101010101010110
```

but with my current program, i am using several things i am not very comfortable with(structures, using arrays inside of these structures and using for loops to take multiple inputs from the user to assign them to respective parts in the structure)

here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct stud{
char name[20];
int answerkey[20];
};



void Init();
void readData();
void findGrade();
void printAll();

void main() {
   struct stud s1, s2, s3, s4;
}

void Init () {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
}


void readData(stuct stud s1, struct stud s2, struct stud s3, struct stud s4) {
int correctkey[20];

int i = 0;


       while (i < 4) {

        printf("Please enter the students name");
        scanf("%s", &s1.name[);
        printf("Please enter their respective answers");
        scanf("&d", &s1.answerkey);
        ++i;
        printf("Please enter the students name");
        scanf("%s", &s2.name);
        printf("Please enter their respective answers");
        scanf("&d", &s2.answerkey);
        ++i;
        printf("Please enter the students name");
        scanf("%s", &s3.name);
        printf("Please enter their respective answers");
        scanf("&d", &s3.answerkey);
        ++i;
        printf("Please enter the students name");
        scanf("%s", &s4.name);
        printf("Please enter their respective answers");
        scanf("&d", &s4.answerkey);
        ++i;
        }

        printf("Please type in the right answerkey");
        scanf("%d", &correctkey);



}

void findGrade(answerkey, correctkey) {
int correct = 0;
int j = 0;
char grade[5];
int scorekey, scorehigh;
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            if (answerkey[j] = correctkey[j])
        correct++;
        }
        if (correct <= 20) {
        grade = A;
        else if (correct <= 16)
        grade = B;
        else if (correct <= 14)
        grade = C;
        else if (correct <= 12)
        grade = D;
        else if (correct <= 11)
        grade = F;
        }
        if (s1.correct > s2.correct > s3.correct > s4.correct) {
        highest = s1.correct;
        scorekey = s1.answerkey
        else if (s2.correct > s1.correct && s3.correct && s4.correct)
        highest = s2.correct;
        scorekey = s2.answerkey

        else if (s3.correct > s1.correct && s2.correct && s4.correct)
        highest = s3.correct;
        scorekey = s3.answerkey

        else if (s4.correct > s1.correct && s2.correct && s3.correct)
        highest = s4.correct;
        scorekey = s4.answerkey

}


void printAll () {

        printf("Name\tStudent Answers\t\t\tAnswers-Correct\tGrade");
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%s", s1.name, s1.answerkey, s1.correct, s1.grade);
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%s", s2.name, s2.answerkey, s2.correct, s2.grade);
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%s", s3.name, s3.answerkey, s3.correct, s3.grade);
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%s", s4.name, s4.answerkey, s4.correct, s4.grade);

        printf("answerkey \t\t Highest Score");
        printf("%d \t %d", scorekey, highest);

}
```

Now my question is .. I want to be able to assign(in the read data function) the 4 students to variables s1, s2, s3, s4. How do i account for this in my loop? In my loop(assuming it is correct) i want it to be able to assign it to a variable. This is all so i can access it in my printAll function so i can print the results of each student separately.

Also, how can i print the highest score from all the students entered and the score that they received?

IF there are any issues with my program please let me know.

Thanks alot

Comment: instead of making 4 separate variables, make an array of your struct and access/change each one with `structArray[i]`

Comment: How is this different from your earlier http://stackoverflow.com/q/33808140/2564301? Did you learn something between then and now or (I didn't really check) is this the exact same - bad - code?

Comment: Constructive, thanks for your assistance

Comment: One issue came to mind. `s1.correct > s2.correct > s3.correct > s4.correct` is legal C but oes not do what you think. I'll give you a hint. There are no real booleans in C; the result of the relational operators like ">" are integers. The integer result is 1 if the relation is true, else 0. Now consider that the relational operators are "left-associative"; the expression could be written as `((s1.correct > s2.correct) > s3.correct) > s4.correct`. What are the possible values of `s1.correct > s2.correct`, as an integer? What follows from that?

Comment: Aside from that the code is full of simple language errors and does not compile, e.g. `grade = A;`. The elsif chain in `findGrade()`is also syntactically wrong (I think you are missing curly braces). There is also a curly brace missing to close the function body (or rather, in the middle the `if (s1.correct > s2.correct > s3.correct > s4.correct) {`is never closed. Proper formatting would help prevent these simple mistakes. Why don't you start just with a few lines which cyou can compile, and expand from there?

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing i four times in your while loop kind of defeats the purpose of a while loop.

I suggest that instead of using four different variables, you use an array

```
stud students[5]
```

then in your while loop you could condense this to

```
 while (i < 5) { // 5 since you want indexes 0-4

    printf("Please enter the students name");
    scanf("%s", students[i].name);
    printf("Please enter their respective answers");
    scanf("&d", students[i].answerkey);
    ++i;
 }
```

EDIT: In response to your comment, I suggest that you review how to use arrays. there are several places in your code where you could easily simplify things by using arrays. For example, in your print function, changing to an array of students would allow you to

```
void printAll () {
    printf("Name\tStudent Answers\t\t\tAnswers-Correct\tGrade");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\t%s", students[i].name, students[i].answerkey, students[i].correct, students[i].grade);
    }

    printf("answerkey \t\t Highest Score");
    printf("%d \t %d", scorekey, highest);
}
```

I am not entirely sure about some of the things you are trying to accomplish since your main function is mostly empty, but it looks like you are declaring your stud variables in the main function. This means that only the main function can access the student variables unless you pass them to the other functions.

If you are having compiler issues, one reason is that the printAll() function tries to access s1,s2,s3,s4, but it can't access them because they aren't declared in a scope that printAll() can see. Your first option is to move the student variables outside the main function in to the global scope so that every function can see them. To make a variable global, you just need to move it outside of any function. I.e.

```
struct students[5];

void main(){

}
```

The other option is to add parameters to printAll() (similar to your readData function) so that the main function can give these variables to printAll(). i.e.

```
printAll(stuct stud s1, struct stud s2, struct stud s3, struct stud s4)
```

or if you decide to change the student variables to an array

```
printAll(struct stud students[])
```

I noticed that your init function initializes i and j to 0, but again you have a problem with scope here. Just because your variables are named the same, does not mean that they reference the same variables. In fact, the i and j in your init function has no effect on the i and j in your readData and findGrade function. Again the problem is that since you are declaring i and j inside of Init(), only init can see them. In readData, you are re-declaring another variable which also happens to be called i that only readData can see. I suggest that you remove i and j from your Init function because it is fine that readData and findGrade own their own i and j variables since they don't need to share these variables with other functions.

I suggest you also read up on scope in the c language.

Lastly, your main function is empty. You may already know this, but your program will not do anything unless you write code in the main function.

Comment: How would i account for this in the other parts of my code? To be honest with you i just want to get something working before i think about improving/making it more concise.

Comment: @BodyBingers You are probably trying to take one step too many at once. Toy around for a day with a simple array of ints. Make it global, read in ints from the console with scanf, print them with printf, let the user input an arbitrary index and print the int at that index. Just 20 or 50 lines of code. Get comfortable with your build provess and editor. THEN do the same with a SINGLE, very simple struct (say of an int and a float). Set its fields with some user input, print the fields. Only THEN have an array of these structs. Only THEN have an array *inside* the struct.